# Measure of similarity between two multivariate samples

Tags: multivariate-analysis, sample, computational-statistics, distance

I have two samples from a multivariate distribution. One is approximate and the other is exact. My aim is to measure the similarity between the approximate sample and the exact sample. In particular, I want to emphasise differences in the tail of the distribution.

Ultimately I'll use this measure to compare the performance of a number of approximate samples produced using different methods. Before I was estimating the KL divergence between the two distributions using the [FNN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/FNN/index.html) package in R. But my supervisor had concerns this did not stress differences in the distribution tails enough.

Does anyone have any recommendations of a good measure for this problem? Ideally it would be easy to implement empirically or, even better, have an R package to do so.

I've come across this problem as part of my PhD in computational statistics.

Comment: We're not assuming multivariate normality, I take it? And we don't have enough data to estimate a covariance matrix?  Because if we were and you did, then you could use the result that squared mahalanobis distances have a $\chi^2$ distribution.

Comment: Aah okay, assuming multivariate Normality is probably not appropriate, some of the distributions are multimodal. We do have enough data to estimate a covariance matrix though - there are 10^4 observations available to play with!